# How to parse flags and value in a string to a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, string, dictionary, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, *, args: str):
    #do stuff here
```

What I want is that if the user enter this command:
**!embed --title Friends --description Friends are very precious** then the bot would send embed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCorm.jpg).

Same for other options too. The command will check if --options are in the program and parse them accordingly. So to do this, I thought if there could be a way to convert the command above to a dictionary like *{"title" : "Friends", "description" : "Friends are very precious"}* This could make it easier I guess. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps the `argparse` module is what you're looking for?

Comment: I got recommended for it but I didn't understood what to do 

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py 2.0 allows for you to create flags for your commands.
Here is an example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class BasicFlags(commands.FlagConverter):
  member: discord.Member

@commands.command()
async def flags_test(ctx, *, flags: BasicFlags):
  await ctx.send(flags.member)
```

This will be invoked by `{prefix}flags_test member: <member>`

Don't like `flag_name:`, but prefer `--flag-name` instead?
No problem:

```py
 from discord.ext import commands

class PosixLikeFlags(commands.FlagConverter, prefix='--', delimiter=' '):
  member: discord.Member

@commands.command()
async def flags_test(ctx, *, flags: BasicFlags):
  await ctx.send(flags.member)
```

This will be invoked using `{prefix}flags_test --member <member>`

Official guide:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/commands.html#ext-commands-flag-converter

Comment: I am discord.py 1.7 user

Comment: I can advise you to think about using discord.py 2.0. It's not much different from your version, but it contains a lot of useful features. Or you can use regex to do what you want but it’s more complicated.